# Cannot clone Mercurial repo - abort: repository http://hg.something.com/something error

Tags: version-control, mercurial, clone, fedora

I ran this command to clone my repo

```
[19:07:19 root /data]$  hg clone http://hg.something.com/something dir
abort: repository http://hg.something.com/something not found!
[19:07:19 root /data]$
```

I am not sure why hg says it cannot find the repo when I can access the repo `http://hg.something.com/something` from my web browser. Also the same command works from my colleague's machine. And `ping` hg.something.com works fine. One more thing is I have the same repo cloned using the same command in the same directory a few days back. `hg` is totally operational inside that directory.

Any hint what may be causing this problem?

**PS**: I can't use SSH. I have to stick to http.

Comment: Should you be using https rather than http?

Comment: @Nanhydrin Tried that too. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the peculiar problem. I had copied the repo link from a web browser that looked like this-

[image]

If you see there is a small character ( red circle ) that indicates that the repo is a link. When I copied the whole command, this character also got copied. But when I pasted this command into my linux terminal, it turned into an invisible character and as such I could never spot it but mercurial could.

When I pasted the whole command into vim, it showed up the "invisible" character like this-

```
hg clone <200b>http://hg.something.com/fs
```

So that invisible character was the [zero width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm).

Quite an insidious bug though!